# Wrapping elements in one element with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to build a mega menu and i want to wrap all sub ul elements into one div, so i can make this div flex-box to display them in a row.

I could manage to get all uls and wrap them with a div but i dont know how to make it sub element of relevant li item. You can see code snippet below.

Thanks in advance.

```js
const octo = document.querySelector("#octo");
const first_level_ul_items = octo.querySelectorAll("#octo>li>ul");
const second_level_ul_items = octo.querySelectorAll("#octo>li>ul>li>ul");
const first_level_ul_wrapper = document.createElement("div");
first_level_ul_wrapper.classList.add("mega-menu-wrapper");
let org_html = "";

Array.from(first_level_ul_items).map((e, index) => {
  if (index != 0) {
    e.parentElement.classList.add("is-mega-menu");
  }
  org_html += e.outerHTML;
});

const new_html = "<div class='mega-menu-wrapper'>" + org_html + "</div>";
```

```html
<ul id="octo">
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Expected result is:

```html
<ul id="octo">
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li class="is-mega-menu"><a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <div class="mega-menu-wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: If you're not going to use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: didnt know that about js `.map()`, im doing it with `for...in` right now

Comment: _"...and add the expected result"_ ;)

Comment: @Andreas added expected result too :D

Comment: @Teemu problem is i dont know how to wrap all uls under that li. i gave a class name to li but cant wrap it's sub uls into one div.

Comment: @Teemu because i dont know how to do it. i dont know how to select relevant `li`

Comment: `.closest("li")`

Comment: @Andreas im trying that thank you

Comment: Have I understood correctly, the UL elements are already inside the relevant LIs, you just want to wrap them with a div?

Comment: @Teemu yes that's it. I want to wrap them in a `div` and that `div`should be sub element of that `li`

Comment: @Andreas i couldnt do it because i cant find the `closest("li")` outside of for each.

Comment: OK, then you'd need a recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```js
const octo = document.querySelector("#octo");
const first_level_li_items = octo.querySelectorAll("#octo>li");

first_level_li_items.forEach((e) => {
  if (e.querySelectorAll("ul").length > 0) {
    e.classList.add("is-mega-menu");
    let link = e.querySelectorAll("a:first-child")[0].outerHTML;
    e.innerHTML =
      link +
      '<div class="mega-menu-wrapper">' +
      e.innerHTML.replace(link, "") +
      "</div>";
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="octo">
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 1</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 2 - UL 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Notice, that this works only when you've two levels, if a nested ul contains another nested ul, this will fail. Also, it's not a good practice to set outer/`innerHTML` of an element existing in the DOM, it's very error prone, and setting it can easily lead to bugs hard to find.

Comment: @Teemu since im not that good at javascript, this is all i can do. :) now all `ul`s are in one `div`

Comment: @Teemu do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Like said in a comment, you need a [recursive approach](https://jsfiddle.net/9rp2u4yc/).

Comment: @Teemu what kind of javascript master are you? :O I'm studying and trying to understand your code right now, thanx a lot. :)

Comment: I consider being on advanced level only, not a master = ). [Recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#recursion) is a handy tool whenever you need to iterate through a collection containing unknown amount of levels of nested mebers.

Comment: @Teemu never heard of Recursion but i'm reading the link you just gave me. thank you again!

Comment: I made some more comments to the [fiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/9rp2u4yc/1/), maybe it helps.

Comment: @Teemu it helps more than you can imagine, i really appreciate that! :))) i was console logging everything :D